# Reasons to use SequenceFile instead of text file in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

What are the reasons to use SequenceFile instead of a text file?

I'm guessing that they are good since input/output comes to serialization, instead of parsing an object, if that object needs to be used multiple times.

Also, I read that it performs compression of the file, so it takes less space and that it is good to aggregate many small files into one large one.

Are this arguments valid and what else?

Answer (score 2):

- Binary data (as in SequenceFiles) is usually more compact than text data (TextFiles) even without explicit compression. So less data needs to be read from/written to the hard disks. The space savings depend on the data that is written.
- Reading binary data is more CPU efficient than String parsing.

However,

- SequenceFiles cannot be read humans and
- are bound to a specific object type / class, whereas text data can be interpreted in different ways as needed.